# How to truncate last two letters in a string and convert to number in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, truncate

I have an Oracle table that shows a column 'Received Quantity' as a string. How do I remove the last two letters in that string and convert the rest to a number?

```
Select receipt_number
      ,item_name
      ,received_quantity
from item_table
```

The result is:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+
|    Rcpt 01|Kool GLue |234CS  |
+-----------+----------+-------+
|    Rcpt 02|Red GLue  |10CS   |
+-----------+----------+-------+
|    Rcpt 03|Bad GLue  |1000CS |
+-----------+----------+-------+
```

I need help with code to remove the 'CS' in the field and convert the numbers to a number and then calculate the sum of all those numbers.

Eventually, I want to Calculate the Sum of number of Cases for all those items.

The code I'm trying is:

```
Select receipt_number
      ,item_name
      ,SUM (to_number(cast(received_quantity, -2)))
from item_table
group by receipt_number, item_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I do it

```
Select receipt_number
      ,item_name
      , SUM(TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(received_quantity,'CS'))))

from item_table

group by receipt_number, item_name
```

There are many others

Comment: I tried this code as it seemed simple. It worked for me. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it very very much.

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way is to simply remove any character that is not a number using `regexp_replace()`:

```
Select receipt_number,
       item_name,
       SUM(to_number(regexp_replace(received_quantity, '[^0-9]', ''))) as quantity
from item_table
group by receipt_number, item_name;
```

That would also cleanup strings like `CS1234`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it very very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING` so answer can be:

```
Select receipt_number
  ,item_name
  ,SUM (to_number(cast(SUBSTR(received_quantity, 1, LENGTH(received_quantity) - 2), -2)))

from item_table

group by receipt_number, item_name
```

Comment: I am so sorry. I misinformed that I was working with SQL Server. I am actually working on an Oracle Database. I guess the LEFT function doesn't work on Oracle?

Comment: you have SUBSTR function which is like SUBSTRING. you also can use LENGTH instead of LEN function